# Java Help (possibly a glitch in eclipse)

Tags: java, string, equals

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;



public class cominback{
    public static void main(String args[]){
      Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println(" please enter a password:");
      String x = key.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Connfirm your password:");
      String y = key.nextLine();
      if ( x == null)
          System.out.println("please restart the program:");
      if (x != y)
          System.out.println("wrong password");
      if (x == y )
          System.out.println("you are logged in");

    }
}
```

It always print out wrong password for even when the input is same passwords. how can i fix this problem? did i do something wrong or is it my eclipse glitching?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `equals` method to compare two string like:

```
if (x.equals(y))//password matches
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` check against reference. Use `equals()` instead for checking if tow string are meaningfully equals. Use the following code snippet - f

```
if( x.equals(y) ){}
if( !(x.equals(y)) ){}
```

**Note:**

```
String str1 = "string one";
String str2 = str1;
String str3 = "string two";

System.out.println( str1.equals(str3) ); //false; meaningfully not equals.
System.out.println( str1 == str2 ); //true; referencing same String content
System.out.println( "string one".equals(str1) ); //true; meaningfully equals
```